# Unity bounce synchronously

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get some balls to bounce rhythmically. I have 10 balls, each with speed v, v * 1, v * 2 ... to v * 10 bouncing off some walls. In theory they should bounce in half the time each if they have double speed. At first it works fine. But after a while it gets desynchronized. And they no longer bounce at the "mathematically correct" intervals. I have tried with the 2d physics engine (0 friction, 1 bounce) and with kinematic bodies doing the rebounds in code with OnCollisionEnter2D, but the same happens in both cases, they get out of sync. I suppose this is because the calculations of the physics engine are not exact and after a while the synchrony is lost. Is there any way to make the balls bounce synchronously [image: bounce synchronously]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWbDf.png), each in exactly half the time of the other if they have twice his speed? Now I'm testing with bounces without angles, from top to bottom, but it should work also with bounces with angles.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: It has no complexity. For dynamic bodies (0 friction, 1 bounce) Vector2 m_speed = new Vector2(0f, 1f); at start() rb1.velocity = m_speed; rb2.velocity = m_speed*2; rb3.velocity = m_speed*2; an so on... for kinematic bodies at OnCollisionEnter2D: speed = m_lastFrameVelocity.magnitude; direction = Vector2.Reflect(m_lastFrameVelocity.normalized, collisionNormal); rbX.velocity = direction * m_speed ... (* 1, * 2, * 3 ...); Similar results in both cases. Worst on kinematic bodies.

Comment: It's worst on kinematic bodies because the OnCollisionEnter2D function timing is inaccurate if you are looking for precision.